# Are there alternative to APNs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, apple-push-notifications

The iOS app that i'm writing will not have access to the internet, only to a local network, but it will still need to receive notification from our server in the LAN, even when the app is suspended. Is there an out of the box solution similar to APNs out there? I've heard of pushwoosh, Anyone have experience with it?

If I have to implemented all by myself, does anyone have some information about how to do so? It seem a bit crazy to reimplement it ....

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No, if you want to send push notifications they must come through APNS.
I've not used pushwoosh before, but assume they are similar to other services such as UrbanAirship in that they give you a nice way to set up and manage your notifications, but they are still going through APNS.

Comment: would you know how complex would it be to implement a custom apns?

Comment: You can't. You may be able to do something with a jailbroken device, but I wouldn't know about that. If you're using standard iOS you have to go through APNs, there is no other way.

Comment: What if you program low level socket connection and listening for tcp connection to receive packets ... ?

Comment: OK, not quite the same as push notifications, but you could register as a VOIP app, this will allow you to have a socket connection while in the background. (You won't be allowed to publish on the store with this.) More info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12

Answer (score 0):

iOS devices periodically check in with the APNS service (using a proprietary Apple protocol which is not documented) in order to generate and maintain the devicetoken+pushmagic pair.  This behavior is part of device hardware/OS, can't be modified, and is allowed to do things which your application cannot do.

If you try to do it yourself, your application will have to deal with all the limitations and constraints of the iOS environment which will make it very difficult if not impossible. As mentioned by JamesP, jailbreaking may let you bypass some of the restrictions (but not all) but it is still a non trivial amount of work even then.

Comment: I'm thinking of just creating a tcp connection and keeping it open to listen for messages and sending messages to our servers.

Comment: Regular application can't listen or keep open connections unless they are on-screen. There are certain application types (such as GPS) which have more flexibility, but those can have significant impact on battery life.